# WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7 on OSX (Mavericks) won't start

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

***Posting for posterity, no answer required...***

After downloading latest [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) I was surprised to find it wouldn't launch.

Turned out that the execute flag wasn't set on the eclipse executable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough to fix:

1. CD into the directory you installed it in, for example:

   ```
   cd /Applications/Eclipse/WSO2 Studio 3.7/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
   ```
2. Set the execute flag:

   ```
   chmod +x eclipse
   ```

It now works :)

Answer (score 1):

Its already documented @ https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Installation#Installation-Completeinstallation

Cheers